# Tentando passar valores da Controller para a Global.asax.cs para preencher as sessões

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Quando tento passar alguma valor de minha controller para a `Global.asax` os valores recebidos na global são sempre nulos.

Controller:

```
public class LoginController : Controller 
{
    DataContext db = new DataContext(); 
    public ActionResult Index()  
    {      
        MvcApplication M = new MvcApplication()
        var U = db.usuarios.single(u=> u.Id == 1);
        M.SetCarregarDadosUsuario(U);
    }
}
```

Global:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication {
    public Usuarios usuarioSession = new Usuarios();

    protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(){
        if (Context.Handler is IRequiresSessionState || Context.Handler is IReadOnlySessionState){
            CarregarDadosUsuario();}  
        }
        private void CarregarDadosUsuario(){
            if(usuarioSession.Id >0){                    
                var loadU = GetCarregarDadosUsuario();                    
                HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("UsuarioImagem", loadU.UrlImg);                    
                HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("UsuarioNome", loadU.Nome);                    
                HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("UsuarioSessao", loadU.SessaoID);                    
                HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("UsuarioFilial", loadU.FilialID);            
            }        
        }        
        public void SetCarregarDadosUsuario(Usuarios user) {            
            this.usuarioSession = user;                           
        }        
        public Usuarios GetCarregarDadosUsuario(){            
        return this.usuarioSession;        
    }    
}
```

Gostaria de saber como faço para passar um lavor de minha Controller para a Globlal.asax.cs para preencher minhas sessões.

Pois a finalidade das sessões será para adicionar valores no arquivo layout e definir permissões para não realizar consultar a banco a todo instante.
Exemplo:

```
<div class="user-img-div user-basic basic-perfil-borda">
    <img src="/Content/NewTheme/img/@Session["UsuarioImagem"]" class="img-thumbnail" />
</div>
```

Comment: Por que você quer fazer isso? Possivelmente não é a melhor forma de fazer.

Comment: Quero gravas as sessões para utiliza-las depois, no meu arquivo de _layout, poderia me dizer qual seria a melhor forma ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Há várias formas de se fazer isso, vou te passar duas. Você pode fazer com sessão mesmo, porém você está criando a sessão de forma errada.

**Com sessão**

```
DataContext db = new DataContext(); 
public ActionResult Index()  
{      
    var U = db.usuarios.single(u=> u.Id == 1);
    Session["imagem"] = U.UrlImg;
    Session["nome"] = U.Nome;
    return View();
}
```

A view está correta:

```
<div class="user-img-div user-basic basic-perfil-borda">
    <img src="/Content/NewTheme/img/@Session["imagem"]" class="img-thumbnail" />
</div>
```

**Com Cache**

Você pode jogar no cache a parte que exibe os dados do usuário, sendo assim a requisição com o banco dados e processamento da View será feita apenas uma vez pelo tempo definido. Isso irá dar mais performance à sua aplicação.

- Defina uma View Parcial para exibir os dados do usuário
- Indique que essa View é  `ChildActionOnly` e defina um `OutputCache`

No arquivo UsuarioController.cs:

```
    // multiplicando segundos por minutos
    [OutputCache(Duration = 60 * 60, Location = OutputCacheLocation.ServerAndClient)]
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult DadosUsuario()
    {
        var user = db.usuarios.single(u=> u.Id == 1);
        return View(user);
    }
```

View (Views/Usuario/DadosUsuario.cshtml):

```
@model MeuProj.Usuario

<div class="user-img-div user-basic basic-perfil-borda">
        <img src="/Content/NewTheme/img/@model.UrlImg" class="img-thumbnail" />
</div>
```

Para chamar a View Parcial, provavelmente na _Layout.cshtml

```
@Html.Action("DadosUsuario", "UsuarioController")
```

Comment: Vlw mano, obrigado, ajudou bastante.